# whats wrong in this code i want to send 100 messages in viber using python code

Tags: python, viber, viber-bot-python

This is my code. I want to send 100 messages in Viber using Python code, and it gives this error:
text_message: TextMessage = TextMessage(text=message, to=recipient)
TypeError: TextMessage.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'to'

i changed 'to' 'to receiver', it still doesn't work

```
 ''''''

import time
from **********
from *************************
from *******************************

viber = Api(BotConfiguration(
    name='MyBot',
    avatar='http://viber.com/avatar.jpg',
    auth_token='*******************************'
))

message = "Hello"
recipient = "1234567890"

for i in range(100):
    text_message = TextMessage(text=message, to=recipient)

    viber.send_messages(text_message)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: pls remove API related keys, Auth tokens from code...People may miss use them...You are not allowed to paste them on public sites

Comment: okay i delete it

Comment: A quick check of the API documentation shows that `TextMessage` takes one argument. What leads you to believe that it takes two?

Comment: Dont delete entire line...Just mark them as `***` on keys

Comment: Beyond deleting/masking your keys, *regenerate* them. Anyone above a certain reputation level here can view past revisions of questions. Until you regenerate, your keys are at risk.

Answer (score 1):

`TextMessage` only takes one argument: `text`.

The keywordargument `to` belongs to the `send_messages` method.

example:

```
text_message = TextMessage(text=message)

viber.send_messages(text_message, to=recipient)
```